# Having trouble converting a date string to a unix timestamp

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, unix-timestamp

So I have a script which uses the following imports:

```
import sys
import os.path
import requests
import json
import csv
import glob2
import shutil
from time import sleep
from time import gmtime, strftime
import time
from datetime import datetime
```

I'm trying to convert `row[15]` which is a date string that looks like `"23/03/2015 00:00"` (read from a csv) into unix time.

This is what that portion of code looks like:

```
{"name":"referral_date", "value": time.mktime(datetime.strptime(row[15], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%S").timetuple()) }
```

Every time I try it, it comes back with this:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mktime'
```

And yet, in a seperate test file, i've tried the following:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

mylist = ["23/03/2015 00:00"]
test = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(mylist[0], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%S").timetuple())
print(test)
```

Which, as you'd expect, results in `1427031000.0` - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look over your code: somewhere you've probably declared a variable called `time` which is a string. It's trying to call `mktime` on that variable, which is why your error refers to a `str` object.

The easiest way to resolve this is to change the name of the `time` variable to something else. If you wanted to fix the issue without changing that variable name, you could import `time` with a different name like this:

```
import time as timelibrary
```

And then call `timelibrary.mktime`.

Comment: Thanks @OrangeFlash81 - that did the trick. Now I need to somehow figure out how to set the timestamp to midnight...